# "which took off a good ten of his fifty years" meaning?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "which took off a good ten of his fifty years"

Above line is from Chapter 1 of the book "Journey to the Centre of the Earth" by Jules Verne.

My confusion:

> Is it talking about period from 40 to 50 OR from 50 to 60 years of age?

Comment: You should have provided more context, instead of expecting us to find the text online.

Comment: It's not even context, just write the full sentence. At the very least you quoted your source, which helped users find the original text.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I already realised my mistake and have said so in comments of individual answers too. Didn't know that it's mentioned here too I would have said them here instead otherwise. Thank you for informing though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'A good' before a quantity or amount means *at least* that amount. 'A good ten years' means 'at least ten years'.

> Picture to yourself a tall, thin man, in excellent health, and with a
> fair, youthful complexion which took off a good ten of his fifty
> years.

"which took off a good ten of his fifty years" means 'which took off *at least* ten of his fifty years'

The man had a fair, youthful complexion which made him look at least ten years younger than his real age (fifty years).

> a good *amount*
> idiom
> this much or more of a specific amount
>
> It’s a good half hour’s walk to the stadium from here.

[Good (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/good)

Answer (score 4):

Neither. Look at the context:

> Picture to yourself a tall, thin man, in excellent health, and with a fair, youthful complexion which took off a good ten of his fifty years. His big eyes were constantly rolling behind huge spectacles; and his long thin nose looked like the blade of a knife.

It says that his "fair youthful complexion" (ie his pale smooth skin) took off 10 years.  It means that his good skin made him look 10 years younger than he actually was. He was actually 50, but he looked 40.

I should be so lucky!

Comment: Ooooh! +1. Sorry that you had to take troubles for more context and thanks a lot for the same. Will keep in mind to provide it next time.

Comment: 'A good ten' means '**at least** ten'. That rock weighs a good five tons. It will cost me a good fifty pounds to get my TV repaired. In each case the amount mentioned is a minimum estimate.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey thank you for enlightening me on that. When someone used to put it like that I thought they are, maybe exaggerating or being accurate/showing knowledge. "Atleast" I wouldn't have guessed EVER.

Comment: @InanimateBeing - The meanings of idioms are often hard to guess.